# Como comercializar um framework

Tags: framework

Possuo um Framework de desenvolvimento Web PHP, para desenvolvimento em minha empresa, e a intenção seria partir para o público, porém gostaria de saber, qual melhor maneira de gerar licenças, com o intuito de quem compre, não conseguir passar os arquivos para terceiros e os terceiros consigam acessar sem licença.

Answer (score 1):

PHP é uma linguagem de código aberto. Uma vez tendo acesso aos códigos eu não vejo como impedir seu funcionamento.

Mesmo usando ferramentas como o ZendGuard há formas de reverter o código. Portanto, **não há como impedir**. No máximo você pode dificultar.

Algumas empresas liberam o uso não comercial, e para estarem regularizadas para uso comercial devem começar comprar a licença, sob o risco de sofrerem processos jurídicos.

Outra coisa que poderia funcionar é liberar o seu framework como software livre e ganhar com o serviço de suporte técnico e consultoria.